# Netbeans 8.2 I can't create a PHPUnit test

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

*System: Ubuntu 16.04 / Netbeans 8.2 / phpunit 5.1.3*

**I want to begin using PHPunit with Netbeans.**

I have downloaded PHPunit and configured Netbeans to see phpunit and phpunit-skelgen.phar as shown in this image:

[image: Netneans configuration for phpunit]

I have created a simple class to test, using @assert decorators for the tests, as seen here:

[image: simple class to test]

The problem is that my project reports that PHPUnit is not active ...

[image]

which would seem to explain why I cannot find the file context-menu option to "Create PHPUnit tests", as reported in this image, [from this page.](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html#installing-phpunit)

[image: File context-menu "Create PHPUnit tests"]

**My brain is addled now - how do I configure Netbeans to recognize that I want PHPUnit testing active in the project?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you might have forgotten to mark PHPUnit as a test provider used[image]

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! I should know from long experience that what I am looking for is always right under my nose.

Much appreciated. Have a good weekend!

Comment: And now I have tests running. :)